# How to work with the Next Paragraph on Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to execute an action based on the next paragraph value with the following

```
If ActiveDocument.Paragraph.Next(wdParagraph).Range.Characters.Count > 1 Then
```

However, I think I'm not using the .Next correctly. How can I use it whithin that line of code?

Comment: Maybe you could tell me how to expand my ```Rng``` variable, until the end of the current paragraph in which 4 words from this paragraph are stored in the ```Rng``` variable?

Answer (score 2):

The `Next` method doesn't appear to be available in all versions of Word VBA. According to this site it is specific to Office 365.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/paragraph-next-method-word
However, you are also not using it correctly. The above site shows the following syntax.
`Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Next(Count:=n).Range`
So, the logic is to define the paragraph where you are now (`Paragraphs(1)`) and specify that you are counting paragraphs by that same parameter. Therefore `Next(wdParagraph)` isn't required to specify the subject of your count. Instead, `wdParagraph` would indicate that you wish to specify the 4th paragraph from where you are (wdParagraph = 4), if you had provided that information earlier on in your syntax.