# Error #91, object variable or with block variable not set, .Paragraph.Next method in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

I wanted to learn .Paragraph.Next method from this [Microsoft help page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.next)

I've also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241554/how-to-work-with-the-next-paragraph-on-word-vba) here on Stackoverflow.

I've read both of them 5 times and later copied the example code from Microsoft help page.

I've pasted it with absolutely no changes into Word VBA editor and run it from there.

```
Sub MoveAhead()
    For n = 0 To 8
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Next(Count:=n).Range
        myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        myRange.InsertAfter n + 1 & vbTab
    Next n
End Sub
```

While debugging using F8 key, the first loop runs okey, from n=0 to n=1, but when the second loop is run the macro crashes at `Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Next(Count:=n).Range` line.

[image]

I've just started my adventure with VBA but the fist variable `i` needs no setting, right? Because it's a variable that carries a value - right?

And the second variable `myRange` is correctly set, so what's wrong here?

The code is run from Word VBA editor. No Excel file is open at the time.

Comment: How many paragraphs does your document have? Add the line `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count` and see what I mean. You can't go to the next paragraph cause you don't have enough of them.

Comment: When the macro starts the document is COMPLETELY empty.

Comment: From the documentation, right before that snippet: "This example inserts a number and a tab before the first **nine** paragraphs in the active document."

Comment: I took the file with 100 paragraphs and the code started working like a charm. Sorry for all the trouble. I think I'll just need to reeducate myself towards reading with understanding. Thank You so much @BigBen.